# UICollectionView cells randomly disappear on scroll up or reload functions - iOS 9/Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, ios9, uicollectionviewcell

After going through the solutions here on STO and other blogs, none seem to truly fix the UICollectionView issues others definitely seem to still have to this day!

Avoiding the reload functions initially loads the CollectionVC with no issues and scrolling down to the bottom no issues as well, but the moment I scroll up, random cells go missing. Also, noticed that the delegate method below gets called multiple times as I am scrolling, is this normal?

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

Using any of the reload functions results in random cells .backgroundView disappearing:

```
self.collectionView?.reloadSections(NSIndexSet.init(index: 0))
self.collectionView?.reloadData()
self.collectionView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(cellIndexPathArray)
self.collectionView?.reloadInputViews()
```

Subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout with different override options seems to have no effect.

```
class CustomCollectionFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    //self.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Vertical
    return true
    //invalidateLayoutWithContext(invalidationContextForBoundsChange(newBounds))
    //return super.shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds)
}

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    /*
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    print(attributes)
    let contentSize = collectionViewContentSize()
    return attributes?.filter { $0.frame.maxX <= contentSize.width && $0.frame.maxY < contentSize.height }
     */

    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    return attributes

}

}
```

CollectionVC.swift

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

class CollectionVC: UICollectionViewController {

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //Register cell class
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

////////////////////////////////
//UICollectionViewDataSource
////////////////////////////////
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return appDelegate.chosenImageArray.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // Configure the cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

     let bgView = appDelegate.chosenImageArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? UIView

      if bgView != nil {
                cell.backgroundView = bgView
                cell.hidden = false
                cell.backgroundView?.hidden = false
             }
     return cell
  }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                           sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return appDelegate.deviceSize
    //Tried with different sizes CGSize(100,100) - (200,200) and 0 on insets, no difference
 }

////////////////////////////////
//UICollectionViewDelegate
////////////////////////////////
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    //do various stuff with selected cell and segue to next view, no issues here

 }

}
```

Hope someone can tell me it's just a few settings I need to input, as this issue seems random and maybe just a bug with UICollectionView? Anyway, thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is normal every time you scroll the collection view cell and it becomes visible on screen again the delegates get called. 
It is getting re used.

In cellForItemAtIndexPath you have

```
 let bgView = appDelegate.chosenImageArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? UIView
```

this above line.
I guess in appDelegate.chosenImageArray you have all the UIViews.

**Possible fix**
**Do not store the UIView directly on array create a NSObject model class and create required properties in it.**

-Try to create a NSObject model class which should have all the relevant properties like UIImage , name etc... as per your requirement.
Store that NSObject class in array. Here NSObject class is your model class which you are going to store in your array.
Now in delegate   **cellForItemAtIndexPath** - 
     let bgViewModel = appDelegate.yourModelClassArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? yourModelClass

```
            cell.backgroundView = bgViewModel.bgView
```

remove cell.hidden = false & cell.backgroundView?.hidden = false it is not required.

Comment: Hi Manish, thanks for the fast reply. Tried storing it as NSObject class and calling from the model class as suggested, but still get the cells missing when scrolling up. I tried using a dummy image for all the cells and still get the missing cell.backgroundView on random cells when I scroll up.

Comment: Found that assigning directly -> cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "backIcon-square.png")) works correctly and smoothly...

Comment: Are you aware of creating a custom cell , If yes you can create a custom cell and put a UIImageView on  custom cell and assign image to it accordingly ..
If not you can
Try using ->  cell.contentView = <ImageView>  
in place of backgroundView

Comment: Found that assigning directly -> cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "backIcon-square.png")) works correctly and smoothly


Was this answer of your's is  the required solution for it ?